# Can the structure of React context update dynamically?

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I'm using React context to store data about what component to to render to the screen. These component are recursively rendered, but that is not necessarily important to this question.

Think of something like this (Actual code is more complicated and uses useReducer instead of useState, but this should hopefully paint the picture):

**Parent Component**

```
const context = {
  'root': { /* arbitrary fields*/},
  'left': { /* arbitrary fields*/},
  'right': { /* arbitrary fields*/},
  'rightTop': { /* arbitrary fields*/},
  'rightBottom':{ /* arbitrary fields*/}
}


const [context, setContext] = useState(viewportContext); // this will be useReducer

return (
  <div>
    <ViewportContext.Provider value={context}>
      <Port id="root" setContext={setContext} />
    </ViewportContext.Provider>
  </div>
);
```

The list of components is going to be able to dynamically grow and shrink during runtime. Can the structure of the Context update dynamically to accomodate this?

**e.g.**

```
{
  'root': { /* arbitrary fields*/},
  'left': { /* arbitrary fields*/},
  'right': { /* arbitrary fields*/},
  'rightTop': { /* arbitrary fields*/},
  'rightBottom':{ /* arbitrary fields*/},
  'foo':{ /* arbitrary fields*/},
  'bar':{ /* arbitrary fields*/}
}
```

Or do I need a structure like the following?

```
{
  pages: {
    'root': { /* arbitrary fields*/},
    'left': { /* arbitrary fields*/},
    'right': { /* arbitrary fields*/},
    'rightTop': { /* arbitrary fields*/},
    'rightBottom':{ /* arbitrary fields*/},
    'foo':{ /* arbitrary fields*/},
    'bar':{ /* arbitrary fields*/}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure it can, a React context is just a way to have an arbitrary Javascript value be accessible to every component below the provider. The value itself doesn't matter to React, it can be whatever you want and change however you want, as long as the consumers know how to deal with it.